# Prepending a string to a Smarty variable

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3

I'm looking for a way to prepend a string to a Smarty variable. I have a dynamic form having element-names like `input-1` (where 1 is the id of the setting/field).

I've tried to do this with `{capture}{/capture}` but this only seems to work the first time (as the fields are displayed by a loop).

Is there an opposite function from `|cat:'text'` for Smarty, or do I have to:

1. Create my own modifier
2. Rename inputs

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood but wouldn't it be that simple? `{'input-'|cat:$id}`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve, but there is an alternative syntax to `cat`, using backticks (and much more elegant and clear imho):

Using cat:

```
{"my string"|cat:$my_var|cat:"other string"|cat:$other_var}
```

The same, using bacticks:

```
{"my string `$my_var` other string `$other_var`"}
```

Using backticks, you can easily place your variables anywhere inside the string:

```
{"input-`$id`"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need it in a variable? I usually do these things like this:

```
<input name="input-{$id}" type="..." />
```

If you need it in a variable you can use `{assign}`:

```
{assign var="name" value="input-$id"}
<input name="{$name}" type="..." />
```